# C/C++ assign pointer address of DWORD array

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, portable-executable

I am programming a C/C++ PE Parsing library where I use DLL or exe to extract info about directories and headers. My prblem is when I extract the export address and get the address of functions, I don't know how to use that address to point it to the array with the number of export functions exported

```
DWORD ExportRVA = PEHeader->optional.data_directory[0].virtual_address;
image_export_directory* Exports = (image_export_directory*)(RVAToOffset(ExportRVA)+BaseAddress);

ExportTable.nNames = Exports->number_of_names;
ExportTable.nFunctions = Exports->number_of_functions;
ExportTable.pFunctions = Exports->address_of_functions;
ExportTable.nNames = Exports->address_of_names;
ExportTable.pNamesOrdinals = Exports->address_of_name_ordinals;
```

Do I have to assign a pointer to array like

```
DWORD * AddrFunctions;
```

changing the pointer address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address_of_functions` and `address_of_names` fields are RVAs to arrays of RVAs to the actual function entry points and names, respectively, whereas the `address_of_name_ordinals` field is an RVA to an array of WORD values, eg:

```
#define RVAToPtr(RVA) ( ((LPBYTE)BaseAddress) + ((DWORD)(RVA)) )

image_export_directory* Exports = (image_export_directory*) RVAToPtr(PEHeader->optional.data_directory[0].virtual_address); 

ExportTable.nFunctions = Exports->number_of_functions; 
ExportTable.nNames = Exports->number_of_names; 
ExportTable.pFunctions = (PDWORD) RVAToPtr(Exports->address_of_functions); 
ExportTable.pNames = (PDWORD) RVAToPtr(Exports->address_of_names); 
ExportTable.pNamesOrdinals = (PWORD) RVAToPtr(Exports->address_of_name_ordinals); 

for (DWORD i = 0; i < ExportTable.nFunctions; ++i)
{
    void *FuncPtr = (void*) RVAToPtr(ExportTable.pFunctions[i]);
    char* FuncName = (char*) RVAToPtr(ExportTable.pNames[i]);
    WORD FuncOrdinal = ExportTable.Base + ExportTable.pNamesOrdinals[i]; 
    ...
}
```

Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Did you assume that PDWORD* pFunctions; PDWORD* pNames; PWORD* pNamesOrdinals; ?

Comment: No, I did not.  `pFunctions` and `pNames` need to be `PDWORD` instead of `PDWORD*`, and `pNamesOrdinals` needs to be `PWORD` instead of `PWORD*`.

Comment: FuncName is not printing the function name :/